# How to create and use Ingest pipeline with Spring data elastic search

Tags: spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I need to upload pdf file in elastic search for searching content inside the pdf file. I used ingest pipeline curl APIs through postman it works fine but, i am unable integrate and use in my spring boot project to index and search on pdf file. Can anyone suggest me how to create and use ingest pipeline in spring data elastic search.

for index and document indexing we just annotated on entity class but for ingest pipeline how we use it.

```
@Document(indexName = "blog", type = "article")
public class Article {

    @Id
    private String id;
    
    private String title;
    
    @Field(type = FieldType.Nested, includeInParent = true)
    private List<Author> authors;
    
    // standard getters and setters
}
```

I need clarity in spring boot perspective how to configuring ingest pipeline and how to use it in entity class to save the file data  to search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not supported in Spring Data Elasticsearch.

And please note that Spring Boot and Spring Data Elasticsearch are different things. Spring Boot can autoconfigure Spring Data Elasticsearch, but that's it